# Implementing a printAnimals method

Tags: java, for-loop, object, if-statement, arraylist

I am trying to implement a printAnimals() method that prints the ArrayList for dogs or prints the ArrayList for monkeys, or prints all animals whose training status is "in service" and whose is Not reserved, depending on the input you enter in the menu. I am trying to correctly write a for loop for both ArrayList that contains if statements, so it will print whatever item in the ArrayList meets the conditions, which are that their trainingStatus equals "in service" and that reserved = false.

I currently have an error under printAnimals() method that says "The method dogList(int) is undefined for type Driver" and another error message that says "The method monkeyList(int) is undefined for type Driver". Do you know how to correctly type a for loop that iterates through an ArrayList and has if statements? Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {
private static ArrayList<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<Dog>();
private static ArrayList<Monkey> monkeyList = new ArrayList<Monkey>();
// Instance variables (if needed)

public static void main(String[] args) {


    initializeDogList();
    initializeMonkeyList();

    // Creates a scanner class object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char option;
    // Displays the menu in loop until the user enters the exit option
    do
    {
        displayMenu();
        option=input.next().charAt(0);
        // If user input is 1, intakeNewDog method is called
        if(option=='1') {
            
            intakeNewDog(input);
        }
        // If the option is 2, the intakeNewMonkey method is called
        else if(option=='2') {
            
            intakeNewMonkey(input);
        }
        // If the option is 3, the reserveAnimal method is called
        else if(option=='3') {
        
            reserveAnimal(input);
        }
        // If the option is 4, the printAnimals method is called to print dog list
        else if(option=='4') {
            
            printAnimals(option);
        }
        // If the option is 5, the printAnimals method is called to print monkey list
        else if(option=='5') {
            
            printAnimals(option);
        }
        // If the option is 6, the printAnimals method is called to print all available 
        animals
        else if(option=='6') {
            
            printAnimals(option);
        }
        // If the option is q, exit message prints and application stops running
        else if(option=='q') {
            
            System.out.print("You have exited the application.");
            break;
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("You have entered an invalid input.");
        }
     }while (option != 'q');


}

// This method prints the menu options
public static void displayMenu() {
    System.out.println("\n\n");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tRescue Animal System Menu");
    System.out.println("[1] Intake a new dog");
    System.out.println("[2] Intake a new monkey");
    System.out.println("[3] Reserve an animal");
    System.out.println("[4] Print a list of all dogs");
    System.out.println("[5] Print a list of all monkeys");
    System.out.println("[6] Print a list of all animals that are not reserved");
    System.out.println("[q] Quit application");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter a menu selection");
}


// Adds dogs to a list for testing
public static void initializeDogList() {
    Dog dog1 = new Dog("Spot", "German Shepherd", "male", "1", "25.6", "05-12-2019", "United 
States", "intake", false, "United States");
    Dog dog2 = new Dog("Rex", "Great Dane", "male", "3", "35.2", "02-03-2020", "United 
States", "Phase I", false, "United States");
    Dog dog3 = new Dog("Bella", "Chihuahua", "female", "4", "25.6", "12-12-2019", "Canada", 
"in service", true, "Canada");

    dogList.add(dog1);
    dogList.add(dog2);
    dogList.add(dog3);
}


// Adds monkeys to a list for testing
//Optional for testing
public static void initializeMonkeyList() {
    Monkey monkey1 = new Monkey("Albert", "male", "8", "9.5", "06-12-2019", "Costa Rica", "in 
service", false, "United States", "17.6", "18.4", "18.1", "Capuchin");
    Monkey monkey2 = new Monkey("Ada", "female", "6", "1.2", "04-18-2020", "Brazil", "Phase 
4", true, "Canada", "13.2", "10.1", "9.9", "Tamarin");
    Monkey monkey3 = new Monkey("Galileo", "male", "7", "7.8", "11-22-2019", "Congo", "Phase 
3", false, "United States", "26.2", "20.3", "21.2", "Guenon");
    
    monkeyList.add(monkey1);
    monkeyList.add(monkey2);
    monkeyList.add(monkey3);

}


// Complete the intakeNewDog method
// The input validation to check that the dog is not already in the list
// is done for you
public static void intakeNewDog(Scanner scanner) {
    scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the dog's name?");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    for(Dog dog: dogList) {
        if(dog.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            System.out.println("\n\nThis dog is already in our system\n\n");
            return; //returns to menu
        }
    }

    // Add the code to instantiate a new dog and add it to the appropriate list
    System.out.println("What is the dog's breed?");
    String breed = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the dog's gender?");
    String gender = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the dog's age?");
    String age = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the dog's weight?");
    String weight = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("When was this dog acquired?");
    String acquisitionDate = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Which country was this dog acquired?");
    String acquisitionCountry = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the dog's training status?");
    String trainingStatus = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Is this dog reserved?");
    boolean reserved = scanner.nextBoolean();
    scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Which country is the dog in service?");
    String inServiceCountry = scanner.nextLine();
    
    Dog dog4 = new Dog(name, breed, gender, age, weight, acquisitionDate, acquisitionCountry, 
    trainingStatus, reserved, inServiceCountry);
    dogList.add(dog4);
    System.out.println("Your entry has been added to the dog list.");
}


    // Complete intakeNewMonkey
//Instantiate and add the new monkey to the appropriate list
    // For the project submission you must also  validate the input
// to make sure the monkey doesn't already exist and the species type is allowed
    public static void intakeNewMonkey(Scanner scanner) {
        scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's name?");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        for(Monkey monkey: monkeyList) {
            if(monkey.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                System.out.println("\n\nThis monkey is already in our system\n\n");
                return; //returns to menu
            }
        }
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's gender?");
        String gender = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's age?");
        String age = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's weight?");
        String weight = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("When was this monkey acquired?");
        String acquisitionDate = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Which country was this monkey acquired?");
        String acquisitionCountry = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's training status?");
        String trainingStatus = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Is this monkey reserved?");
        boolean reserved = scanner.nextBoolean();
        scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Which country is the monkey in service?");
        String inServiceCountry = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How long is the monkey's tail?");
        String tailLength = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's height?");
        String height = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's body length?");
        String bodyLength = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What species is the monkey?");
        String species = scanner.nextLine();
        
        Monkey monkey4 = new Monkey(name, gender, age, weight, acquisitionDate, 
        acquisitionCountry, trainingStatus, reserved, inServiceCountry, tailLength, height, 
        bodyLength, species);
        monkeyList.add(monkey4);
        System.out.print("Your entry has been added to the monkey list.");
    }

    // Complete reserveAnimal
    // You will need to find the animal by animal type and in service country
    public static void reserveAnimal(Scanner scanner) {
        scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter animal type: ");
        String animalType = scanner.nextLine();
        if (animalType.equalsIgnoreCase("Monkey")) {
            System.out.println("Enter the monkey's country of acquisiton: ");
            String country = scanner.nextLine();
            for(Monkey obj: monkeyList) {
                if(obj.getAcquisitionLocation().equalsIgnoreCase(country)) {
                    obj.setReserved(true);
                    System.out.println("This monkey is now reserved.");
                    return;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The monkey entered is not in the list");
        }
        else if (animalType.equalsIgnoreCase("Dog")) {
                System.out.println("Enter the dog's country of acquisition: ");
                String country = scanner.nextLine();
                for(Dog obj: dogList){
                if(obj.getAcquisitionLocation().equalsIgnoreCase(country)){
                    obj.setReserved(true);
                    System.out.println("This dog is now reserved.");
                    return;
                }

            }
            System.out.println("The dog entered is not in the list");
            }  else {
            System.out.println("Type not found");
            }
    
    }

    public static void printAnimals(char option) {
        if (option == '4') {
            System.out.println(dogList);
        }
        else if (option == '5') {
            System.out.println(monkeyList);
        }
        else if (option == '6') {
            // Iterates through dogs
            for (int i = 0; i < dogList.size(); i++) {
                if (dogList(i).getTrainingStatus.equals("in service") && 
        dogList(i).getReserved()==false) {
                    // Prints dogs that are in service and available
                    System.out.println(dogList.get(i));
                }
            
            }
            // Iterates through monkeys
            for (int i = 0; i < monkeyList.size(); i++) {
                if (monkeyList(i).getTrainingStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("in service") && 
            monkeyList(i).getReserved()==false) {
                    // Prints monkeys that are in service and available
                    System.out.println(monkeyList.get(i));
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks for me an error here:

```
if (dogList(i).getTrainingStatus.equals("in service") && 
    dogList(i).getReserved()==false) {
```

This should be:

```
if (dogList.get(i).getTrainingStatus.equals("in service") && 
        dogList.get(i).getReserved()==false) {
```

Try it and let me know if that is now working.